# Illustrator path unite issue

Tags: path

This has me a bit baffled, so any help greatly appreciated.

The wheel to the left is a circle and several line paths. I then outline the paths and 'unite' using the shape tool.

The problem is, the united shape (to the right) alters the 'spoke' weights, even though they were the same size path to begin with.

Why? why?! WHY??!!

See image and http://dribbble.com/shots/1493314-Illustrator-Path-Issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess one solution might be to use rectangles in place of line paths and see if that works better?

Answer (score 0):

I went to your dribble page to see the example; you mention the pixel grid but I believe there's a simpler reason:

**Alignment Tool:**

Based on your example (and me trying to recreate your example), it looks like the lines and the circle were not "aligned" horizontally and vertically before turning them into 'outlined objects.'

You can tell these vectors are not centered on each other because the image on the right (after outlining the strokes) do not form a perfect circle. Whenever I'm drawing a symmetrical object, I use the alignment tool quite often.